# Python TypeError attempting to writerow back to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to open some data from a CSV edit it and then put it back in  the row at column number 12. The edit work (the re.sub element is working correctly) But I am having troubles writing it back into the new 3.csv. Any Advice on how I can do this please? I also belive I need to close the files?

The error I am getting is:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

```
import csv
import re

with open('2.csv', "r") as inFile, open("3.csv", "wb") as outFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile)
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    for row in reader:
        newText = re.sub(r'.*SC', r'SC', row[4])
        writer.writerow(newText)
```

Here is the data I am trying to modify to help understand the code above.

```
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5 
1,2,3,4,DESCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,DEffffSCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,aaaaDESCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,<>DESCRIPTION
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5 
1,2,3,4,SCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,SCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,SCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,SCRIPTION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message I assume Python 3.  Per [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), open files as:

```
with open('2.csv','r',newline='') as inFile, open("3.csv",'w',newline='') as outFile:
```

Also `newText` is just a single string.  To write the file correctly, replace `row[4]` with the substitution, and write the whole row.

```
import csv
import re

with open('2.csv','r',newline='') as inFile, open('3.csv','w',newline='') as outFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile)
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    for row in reader:
        row[4] = re.sub(r'.*SC', r'SC', row[4])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open the `3.csv` file in bytes mode, so may use `"w"` instead of `"wb"` as the mode for `"3.csv"`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3), CSV files should be opened using `newline=''` to ensure that newlines are interpreted correctly.

```
with open('2.csv', "r") as inFile, open("3.csv", "wb") as outFile:
```

should therefore be

```
with open('2.csv', "r", newline="") as inFile, open("3.csv", "w", newline="") as outFile
```

When opening a file in bytes mode, you may only write bytes to that file. You would therefore need to [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) your strings first.

You don't need to explicitly close either file, as you are using the `with` statement, meaning that the context manager will take care of this.